# Every subset of a metric space is open under a continuous map.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.

(a) Suppose that every function $f:(X,d)\rightarrow(X,d)$ is continuous. Prove that any subset of $X$ is open in $(X,d).$

(b) Suppose that the only continuous functions $f:(X,d)\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ are constant functions. Prove that $X$ contains only one point.

The following details are my attempts on part (a) and (b) :

(b) For fixed $y\in X$. Consider the function $f(x)=|x-y|$ where $x\in X$ and $x\neq y$. We see that $f$ is continuous using the reverse triangle inequality. The function $f$ will be constant only when $f(x)=0$ which means that $x=y.$ Thus $X$ is a one-point set. I am not sure this approach will be alright or not.

For part (a), We treat $X$ and $\emptyset$ separately which is obvious that they are open in $X$. Given arbitrary open set $U$ in $X$.... I tried to assert by contradiction but I made no progression. Any ideas are all welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For (b), you have the right idea, but remember that in a metric space, there may not be any notion of addition, subtraction, or absolute value, so $|x-y|$ may not make any sense. Instead, use the metric $d(x,y)$. Show that it is continuous and non-constant if there is more than one point, using the reverse triangle inequality as you say.

For (a), Consider an arbitrary set $A\subset X$. Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct points in $X$. By hypothesis, the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} p & x\in A\\ q & x\not\in A\end{cases}$$ is continuous. How does this imply that $A$ is open? And what if $X$ has only one point so that we cannot choose distinct $p$ and $q$?

Comment: Pedantic note: $0$ and $1$ aren't necessarily points in your metric space. Instead you should be considering arbitrary distinct points $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed.----

Comment: Thanks for useful comments on part (b). I'll dig into details from your hint on part (a). Sweet!

Comment: @AlexS May I ask what is the motivation to construct the function $f$ in part (a) be like that?

Comment: @Nothingone Since the only information about $X$ that we know is that all functions $X\to X$ are continuous, we know we have to construct some function to prove that all sets are open. To prove that an arbitrary set $A$ is open, our function should be somehow related to $A$. Next, it should be simple so we don't have to work too hard. Finally, it would be good to choose something that in most metric spaces would not be continuous to really leverage this very powerful property. The function I chose fits all 3 points. In fact, functions like this are common for this type of proof.